# automatically log in user after password reset

Tags: node.js, everyauth

I'm using everyauth password authentication for registration and login in my node.js application. Right now, when a user resets their password, they have to login once the password is saved. I want everyauth to automatically login the user once they set their password. Is this possible? How can it be done?

Comment: We're going to need a lot more information about how you actually implemented your backend to the everyauth password authentication feature. Once you have a user session, the everyauth module itself doesn't magically invalidate the user's current session.

How are you determining that the user is still logged in -- and why does that cause them to be logged out. It sounds like an implementation detail of your session management, not everyauth itself.

Comment: The password reset doesnt happen when the user is logged in. It's actually from the forgot-password link. When a user clicks on the link, they enter their email address and they are sent a link which they use to set a new password. So I wanted the user to be logged in once they set their password instead of them being taken to the login page to login.

Comment: Aha, I see what you're trying to do. Can't you just pass-through the new password they submit to your auth function, once you've confirmed that the User has been updated with the new password?

Comment: Let me post some code below..